# Why The Navigation View doesn't show up using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following files and I don't know why the navigation bar is not showing.

In the first file I am using NavigationView before ContentView().
File 1:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TwitterCloneApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView{
                ContentView()
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

In second file I am using MainTabView(), but there is no navigation bar space.

File 2

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showMenu = false
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading){
                    MainTabView()

                
            }
           
        
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here it is the MainTabView.

File 3:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainTabView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $selectedIndex){
                FeedView()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedIndex = 0
                    }
                    .tabItem{
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                    }.tag(0)
                ExploreView()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedIndex = 1
                    }
                    .tabItem{
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    }.tag(1)
                NotificationsView()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedIndex = 2
                    }
                    .tabItem{
                        Image(systemName: "bell")
                    }.tag(2)
                MessagesView()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedIndex = 3
                    }
                    .tabItem{
                        Image(systemName: "envelope")
                    }.tag(3)
            
            
        }
    }
    
}

struct MainTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainTabView()
    }
}
```

There is no space for the navigation bar.

[image]

Comment: Try moving NavigationView from WindowGroup to ContentView to start with

Comment: you don't have any `.navigationTitle` nor `.toolBar`. So what should show up?

Comment: A TabView should not be inside a NavigationView/Stack, each tab can have its own but the tab view should be at the very top.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with the code you've posted:

1. Each sub-view within a `TabView` should have its own `NavigationView`.
2. There shouldn't be a `NavigationView` at the top level
3. Each top-level view within a `NavigationView` should have a `.navigationTitle`
4. The `tapGesture` isn't needed to switch between tabs

so you should end up with

```
struct TwitterCloneApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()            
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
struct MainTabView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedIndex){
            NavigationView {
                FeedView()
                    .navigationTitle("Feed")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "house")
            }.tag(0)
            
            NavigationView {
                ExploreView()
                    .navigationTitle("Explore")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            }.tag(1)
            
            NavigationView {
                NotificationsView()
                    .navigationTitle("Notifications")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "bell")
            }.tag(2)
            
            NavigationView {
                MessagesView()
                    .navigationTitle("Messages")
            }
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "envelope")
            }.tag(3)
        }
    }
}
```